# Spring boot data redis doesn't return value from repository

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data

I want to use Redis repository in my spring boot application but every time when I want to reun methods like findById or findByName every time repository return null but when I run functions like findAll or save everything works properly. This is my code:
In main I used this annotaion : @EnableRedisRepository("com.redis.repository.redis")
I created RedisConfig file:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

@Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<?, ?> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
    return template;
}

}
```

I also added annotation @RedisHash above my domain class.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@RedisHash
public class Product {

@Id
private Long id;

private String name;

private String description;

private Double price;

private Double quantity;

}
```

and this is my pom file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Is anyone who know what I did wrong?

EDITED:

I added to field @Indexed and it works properly but for old versions it doesn't work still

Comment: do you have a git repo that you cloud share?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai I don't have git repo but I updated my question. I hope it will be enought

Answer (score 0):

It would be more helpful if you can post your redis version, spring-data-redis version, and the repository code.

Also, you can use the [MONITOR](https://redis.io/commands/monitor) command of redis to see exactly what command was sent to the redis server by your server, which would help to debug.

Comment: I solved my problem by added @Indexed  to field but it doesn't work for old value